# iphone - How to identify a device via bluetooth

Tags: xcode, bluetooth

my question is about  bluetooth ids of a device. My idea is  identify a device by bluetooth id. I do not need bluetooth communication, only know the ids. It is possible? I read that using gamekit library it is possible some communication between iOS devices, but I need to only identify ids of any device (not only the iOS ones).

thanks in advance for any suggestion.